# "Unable to generate sample payload" when testing rules on Business Rules service on Bluemix

Tags: business-rules, ibm-cloud

I was testing my rules through the Decision Services tab for the Business Rules service in the Bluemix console. When I tried to generate the sample payload again (after a while) by clicking on "JSON", an error popped up:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved this by logging out and logging back in to the Bluemix console and navigating to the Decision Services tab of the Business Rules service instance. I was then able to generate the sample payload again.

Comment: It seems it was due to a timeout issue